# Linked questions don't appear after move to new domain

Tags: bug, status-completed, domain-name, links

As an example, here's [a question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/7312/1243) that has a link to [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/7021/1243), but the link is through the old webapps.stackexchange.com domain. This means that neither question shows the other in its list of linked questions.

Are there plans to either fix the link URL's or to make the link algorithm take the old domain into account?

Answer (score 3):

The linked questions rebuild automatically over time, so this should fix itself as questions are loaded and edited.